# Contig Extension with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, genetics, contiguous

I want to add a function to a program that creates dictionaries with dna sequences that receives a contig (incon= initial contig; dna sequence) and extends it to the right by finding overlapping parts in form of keys in dictionaries and concatenating the values with the "+" operator.

I'll give a quick example:

GATTTGAAGC as initial contig

ATTTGAAGC:A is one of many entries in the dictionary

I want the function to search for such an overlapping part (I asked this here yesterday and it worked fine by itself and with specific values but not within the function with variables) that is a key in the dictionary and concatenate the value of that key to the initial sequence (extend the contig to the right) and save the new sequence into `incon` then delete this dictionary-entry and repeat until there are no entries left (this part i haven't even tried yet).

First i want the function to search for keys with length of 9 with values of length 1 (ATTTGAAGC:A) and if there are no overlapping parts for keys with length 8 with values of length 2 (f.e. ATTTGAAG:TG) and so on.

Additional Info:
The Dictionary "suffixDicts" has such entries with values with length from 1 (key has length 14) to 10 (key has length 5).

"reads" is where a list of sequences is stored

When i try to do the steps one after another some work (like the search) and some don't but when i tried to built a function out of it, literally nothing happens. The function is supposed to return the smallest possible extension.

```
def extendContig (incon, reads, suffixDicts):
    incon = reads[0]
    for x in range(1,len(incon)):
        for key in suffixDicts.keys():
            if incon[x:] == key:
                incon = incon+suffixDicts['key']
                print(incon)
            else:
                print("n")
return()
```

I'm very new to Python and there probably are very dire mistakes i made and i would like them to be pointed out. I know that I'm way over my head with this but I'm understanding most parts of the already existing code now but still have problems with implementing something by myself into it, probably due to incorrect synthax. I know there are programs i could use but i would like to understand the whole thing behind it.

edit: As asked for i will add the already given functions. Some of them were already written some parts i wrote based on the given code (basically i copied it with some tweaks). Warning: It is quite a lot:

Reading the Fasta file:
Additional Info:
The Fasta file contains large amounts of sequences in the Form:

> "> read 1
>
> TTATGAATATTACGCAATGGACGTCCAAGGTACAGCGTATTTGTACGCTA
>
> "> read 2
>
> AACTGCTATCTTTCTTGTCCACTCGAAAATCCATAACGTAGCCCATAACG
>
> "> read 3
>
> TCAGTTATCCTATATACTGGATCCCGACTTTAATCGGCGTCGGAATTACT

I uploaded the file here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=52090273537190816031

edit: edited the large blocks of code out it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: First of all, in order to define a proper function in python, all the code underneath it needs to be indented to the right. That's how you identify the code belonging to the scope of that function. Second, why are you passing `incon` as a parameter if you are setting `incon = reads[0]` in the first line? You only need `incon = reads[0]` in this case and drop the extra parameter.

Comment: Third, this is an interesting algorithm to develop and while the problem is well defined, it could use some enhancement specifically by providing more examples of the data set or even adding the entire data set to the question.

Comment: i will edit the whole thing to the initial post but it's a lot. the intends got lost during copy&paste i edited it.

Comment: you need not add all the data set by pasting it here, maybe making it available online and linking back to it here would be an option.

Comment: too late, sorry. shall i delete them from here and upload the file somewhere?

Comment: by *data set* I meant what you're referring to as the Fasta file... No need for the entire code.

Comment: the Fasta file contains about 200000 "reads" as quoted in the initial post. i can upload the file, shall i? sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79465/discussion-between-bassemdy-and-grindbert).